# Flask API MySQL queries

Tags: python, sql, rest, flask

I'm playing around with an inventory database and trying to make a REST api with flask.

I want to be able to hit a url like http://myapp.com/products, which returns JSON of *all* the products in the database. I also want to have an optional parameter of a product id like [http://myapp.com/products/{id}](http://myapp.com/products/%7Bid%7D) and return the product matching the id passed to it. Fairly standard stuff.

My question is about the best way to generate the sql query string based on whether the user passes an id to the url or not.

The quick and dirty I have is:

```
# Products
@app.route('/products/<int:id>/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@app.route('/products', defaults={'id' : 0}, methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def products(id):
    products = []
    if(id != 0):
        cur.execute("""SELECT stuff
        FROM products
        WHERE products.id = %s""", (id,))
    else:
        cur.execute("""SELECT stuff
        FROM products""")
```

This works but just feels wrong, especially when my "stuff" query is a big long query and repeated twice for each condition, minus the WHERE id = %.

What's the better way to generate these queries based on whether the user passes an id to the url?

Answer (score 0):

By default, if there wouldn't be any product ID added to URL, Flask will throw an error because products function needs an id.

I would recommend using Flask-SQLAlechemy, which is an ORM.
Short description:

> It provides a full suite of well known enterprise-level persistence
> patterns, designed for efficient and high-performing database access,
> adapted into a simple and Pythonic domain language.

Using SQLAlchemy, your queries would look like:

```
if(id !=0):
  Products.query.filter_by(id=id).first()
else
  Products.query.all()
```

[SQLACHEMY Docs](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/)

[Flask-SQLAlchemy Docs](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/)

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about sqlAlchemy but I've been reading up and it seems perfect for this.